# <kbd> (yes, still <kbd>) doesn't play nice with lists

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, kbd

Since kbd is disabled here, the pathological sample that triggered this is hosted on meta.gaming for your inspector/firebug/etc. pleasure.

### [View the pathological example](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/formatting-sandbox/717#717)

- [Perfectly innocent source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/81463494-72d4-4380-a64d-79b989d8893e/view-source)
- [Current answer after some `<br/><br/>` love](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/how-to-get-your-dwarfs-inside/3602#3602) (it still doesn't look great)

Comment: looks fine to me, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Kyle: [Here you go](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/kbd%20plus%20lists.png), notice how the <kbd>'s overlap and the general impression is that lines are cramped up together. I _could_ edit it in but I'd lose Jeff's tag.

Comment: I don't know, it looks OK to me. I certainly wouldn't describe it as 'pathological'. PS - you should be able to edit it in without losing the tag.

Comment: How is this bydesign?! The screenshot badp posted is what I'm getting in Google Chrome in Linux, and looks obviously broken.

Answer (score 3):

The list looks decent with these changes (copy/pasting from the way I got it to look halfway decent with the Chrome Inspector):

```css
kbd {
  background: #eee;
  border-color: #ccc;   /* was #ccc #aaa #888 #bbb */
  border-style: outset; /* was solid */
  border-width: 1px;    /* was 1px 3px 3px 1px */
  color: black;
  padding: 0px 2px;     /* was 2px 4px */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ol li, ul li {
  line-height: 20px;    /* was 16 px */
}
```

Obviously this is quite likely to break, well, everything else.

Comment: This issue can easily be fixed by just adding `display: inline-block` to the `kdb` pseudo-tag. MetaSO has this implemented on their "all.css" file for the aforementioned pseudo-tag, but GamingSE/Arqade does not.

Answer (score 0):

This actually looks fine *here*, at the moment:

> You need to define a [`burrow`](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Burrow) for the safe zone, and a civilian
>   [`alert`](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Alerts) that restricts movement to it.
>
> - To create the burrow
>
>   - Press <kbd>w</kbd> to go to the burrows screen
>   - Press <kbd>a</kbd> to add a new burrow
>   - Size the burrow (remember, a  burrow is 3d)
>   - Choose a name, color, etc
> - To create a new alert
>
>   - Press <kbd>m</kbd> to go to the military screen
>   - Press <kbd>a</kbd> to go to the alerts screen
>   - Press <kbd>c</kbd> to create a new alert
>   - Name it with <kbd>N</kbd>
>   - Change the burrow restriction by pressing enter on the burrow while the burrow is highlighted.
> - To activate the alert (as the civilian alert)
>
>   - Press <kbd>enter</kbd> while the alert is highlighted.
>
> ---
>
> - See also:
>
>   - [Military Interface](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Military_interface)
>   - [Scheduling](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Scheduling)

Unfortunately, [it still looks lousy on meta.gaming.SE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/formatting-sandbox/717#717) :-(.

Comment: The boxes do not overlap. Not here, right now, at least. And whether or not the characters should be aligned is probably debateable.