# Overlap of <kbd> elements

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, kbd

Two `<kbd>` elements on adjacent lines overlap each other. On SO the overlap is small enough that the bottom border is still visible, so it looks ok, but on the SE betas the overlap is worse and it ends up looking fairly bad:

[image: Screenshot of the two cases]

On the Unix/Linux beta we've had a couple cases already where this sort of thing showed up; it's common to have a list of keystrokes to accomplish a particular task. Adding a normal line of text right after a line with a button causes tha line to draw too high as well, so it looks like a `line-height` problem. Changing the `line-height` to `160%` makes it look better but might have other drawing implications; I didn't experiment much

Comment: Oh, I just saw [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58760/kbd-yes-still-kbd-doesnt-play-nice-with-lists) in the "Related" view; it appears to be the same problem (although the problem isn't just in lists like that question implies). Sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The "fix" would require line-height to be set to an absurd number, so I don't think this will be "fixed".

In general you should avoid two `<kbd>` elements near each other vertically, just like you'd avoid making your entire post **bold** for example..

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't think this is really an issue.  It is still clear where the boundaries are on the keys.  The fact that they overlap a bit isn't a big deal as far as I'm concerned.

How often are two `<kdb>` elements going to be directly above each other?  I see this as a non-issue.

Comment: I tried to avoid the "this rarely happens" argument with the last paragraph; I think it's going to happen quite a bit on the Unix/Linux SE site. It's definitely not a big deal, it's a cosmetic error, but it looks quite wrong